# Where can I find the DirectX SDK to work on D3D8?

Tags: c++, directx

I know this in unprofessional and probably doesn't follow the question asking conventions on this site, but I cannot find any other, more suitable (in my opinion) network on stackexchange to ask this question:

Where can I download the DirectX 8.0 SDK ? It seems all the download sources have vanished few years ago. Neither does Microsoft host 8.0 setup files anymore.

I have searched first 25 pages of google for "dx8sdk.exe" but not a single link is alive to download it.

Apologies..

**EDIT:**

I failed in finding the full SDK, but was able to get `d3d8.h` and `d3dx8.h` files for 8.0 version. So, if you download 8.1 SDK (easy), install it, and then replace the upper mentioned two files with ones from this thread: http://forum.ghbsys.net/index.php?/topic/2772-help-to-fixx/?pid=24384&mode=threaded you should have a hacky 8.0 SDK installed.

**EDIT2:** [August 2007 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13287) was the [latest one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/08/21/directx-sdks-of-a-certain-age/) to ship with pre-DX9 technology

Comment: Is there any specific reason you'd want to use such an outdated version? It probably wouldn't even work with updated compilers. However, you should be able to just download the latest DirectX SDK and still compile programs using older functions, since most things should be kept for compatibility reasons. If you're starting learning DirectX, don't use an outdated API and learn the current generation (even if that means you might not be able to use your favorite tutorial or book).

Comment: I am actually writing a proxy dll for d3d8.dll to hook Direct3DCreate8 API to acquire a handle to Direct3D device and draw an overlay on a screen that the target application projects. The original source code I have used was developed by someone else and it outputs an error when trying to compile with new versions of the SDK: 'hkIDirect3DDevice8' : cannot instantiate abstract class. I could modify the code to adapt it to new SDK bersions but I was told that 8.0 sdk should open the code fine. So I hoped someone might have had the setup files lefts still.

Comment: Never mind, see my edit

Comment: You should remove the edit and post it as your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to have a DX8 SDK. Most of the older DX9 SDKs include the necessary files for D3D8 (include/lib).

This one includes the required files, for example: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10368

As for the 8.0/8.1 thing, if that's a concern - Microsoft never separated these as DLLs so it's safe to assume that they're quite compatible. One source confirms it being a minor upgrade: ftp://ftp.hercules.com/faqs/eng/her_eng_00044.pdf